# How do I create an HTML "browser" area in Air with ActionScript?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe, air

I found this simple example online for how to add an HTML "browser" area in an Air application:

```
    protected function init():void
    {
        var browser:HTML = new HTML();
        browser.height = 400;
        browser.width = 400;
        browser.x = 10;
        browser.y = 10;
        browser.location = "www.google.com";
        addChild(browser);
    }
```

Only when I run the application, I don't see a browser, but just a blank white area. :/.  I'm a total newb, and I suspect I'm missing something "obvious".  A little help please?

The only other thing that is in Main.mxlm is the wrapper mx:WindowedApplication, which has mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" and creationComplete="init()".

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more code? is this Flex 3 or 4? Flex 4 uses addElement, not addChild.  Also, make sure your browser isn't being placed behind something else.

Comment: Here, I'll put the entire "Main.mxml", since it is pretty small...  I edited the original to contain everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I just needed something like this:

callLater(goToUrl);

where goToUrl is a method that sets the URL instead of something like this:

browser.location = "www.google.com"

Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Flex-IFrame](http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/) I used it a couple of times.

Comment: I don't think iFrame is of any relevance in Air context, since you do have the HTML component that uses WebKit to render html content.

Comment: in my opinion too iFrame is the most powerful solution +1@adnan

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this is a bit stupid and I'm not sure why it does this, but you just need to add `http://` in the start of your location.  I would of thought it would of gone there by default, but I guess not.   Also, if you're using Flex 4, use `addElement`, not `addChild`.